# Babel not outputting flow comments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, static-analysis, babeljs, flowtype

I'm just getting flow setup for the first time and I'm trying to use it on an open source library. I'm trying to use [babel-plugin-transform-flow-comments](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-flow-comments) so that consumers of the library can get the benefit of type checking if they are also using flow.

I currently have only a single file annotated, and it passes all checks:

```
/* @flow */

import React from 'react'

export default function Checkbox({ input, label }: { input: Object, label: string }) {
  return (
    <div className="form-group checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" {...input} />
        {label}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, when I run my `compile` task, I don't see any flow comments at all. I have the package listed in my dev dependencies:

```
"babel-plugin-transform-flow-comments": "^6.22.0",
```

And I have it wired up in my .babelrc

```
  "plugins": ["transform-flow-comments"],
  "presets": ["flow", "es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
```

Yet there's not a single comment in the output:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _extends = Object.assign || function (target) { for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { var source = arguments[i]; for (var key in source) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) { target[key] = source[key]; } } } return target; };

exports.default = Checkbox;

var _react = require("react");

var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

function Checkbox(_ref) {
  var input = _ref.input,
      label = _ref.label;

  return _react2.default.createElement(
    "div",
    { className: "form-group checkbox" },
    _react2.default.createElement(
      "label",
      null,
      _react2.default.createElement("input", _extends({ type: "checkbox" }, input)),
      label
    )
  );
}
```

Hopefully I've missed something simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I should have just reviewed the docs better. The difference is subtle, but while this does not work:

```
export default function Checkbox({ input, label }: { input: Object, label: string }) {
```

This indeed does:

```
export default function Checkbox(props: { input: Object, label: string }) {
```